# Differential and derivative of the trace of a matrix

Tags: matrices, derivatives, matrix-calculus, trace, scalar-fields

> If $X$ is a square matrix, obtain the differential and the derivative of the functions:
>
> 1. $f(X) = \operatorname{tr}(X)$,
> 2. $f(X) = \operatorname{tr}(X^2)$,
> 3. $f(X) = \operatorname{tr}(X^p)$ ($p$ is a natural number).

---

To find the differential I thought I could just find the differential of the compostion function first and then take the trace of that differential. Am I right in saying so? As for the derivative, I have no idea how I should do it for traces. Could anyone please help me out?

**wj32's answer makes sense to me, however, I wonder if it is also possible to solve this question by using the ordinary way of finding differentials and derivatives, namely f(x+dx)-f(x). Is there someone who could maybe show me how this would be done (if possible)?**

Comment: $\operatorname{tr}$ is linear

Comment: @wj32 Ok, so what does that tell me?

Comment: If $f:E\to F$ is linear, then $Df(x)=f$ for every $x\in E$. I'm only familiar with the Fréchet derivative, so I'm not sure what "differential" means. I'll try to post an answer.

Comment: @wj32 thanks, would be highly appreciated :)

Comment: Do you know the chain rule or the product rule? If this is for a class, what's the name of the class?

Comment: @wj32 Its for calculus, we're currently covering vector differentiation.

Comment: @wj32 And aren't the chain rule and the product rule equal to the rules that are used on regular functions?

Comment: Well, sort of. I highly recommend studying the Frechét derivative rigorously if you want to really understand what's going on. I have a series of articles on this at my website which you can find by visiting my profile.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1) The trace is linear and bounded (which is automatic in finite dimension) so its derivative is equal to itself everywhere
$$
df_X(H)=\mbox{tr}(H).
$$

2) This is the composition of the trace with the bounded bilinear map $g:(X,Y)\longmapsto XY$ whose derivative is 
$$
dg_{(X,Y)}(H,K)=g(X,K)+g(H,Y)=XK+HY.
$$
and the bounded linear map $h:X\longmapsto (X,X)$ whose derivative is itself at every point.

So by the chain rule
$$
df_X(H)=d\mbox{tr}_{X^2}\circ dg_{(X,X)}\circ dh_{X}(H)=\mbox{tr}(XH+HX).
$$
And by commutativity of the trace, this yields
$$
2\mbox{tr}(XH).
$$

3) This is a composition again, of the trace with the $p$-linear map
$$
k:(X_1,\ldots,X_p)\longmapsto X_1\cdots X_p 
$$
and the linear map $l:X\longmapsto (X,\ldots,X)$.

The derivative of $k$ is
$$
dk_{(X_1,\ldots,X_p)}(H_1,\ldots,H_p)=H_1X_2\cdots X_p+X_1H_2X_3\cdots X_p+\ldots+X_1\cdots X_{p-1}H_p.
$$

And the derivative of $l$ is itself. So by the chain rule
$$
df_X(H)=d\mbox{tr}_{X^p}\circ dk_{(X,\ldots,X)}\circ dl_X(H).
$$
Using the commutativity of the trace, we find
$$
p\mbox{tr} (X^{p-1}H).
$$

Answer (score 4):

$\newcommand{\tr}{\operatorname{tr}}$I'm not familiar with matrix-ey notation, so I'll just write down what I know.

Let $V$ be a finite-dimensional real vector space (or more generally a Banach space) and let $L(V)$ be the space of continuous linear operators on $V$. The trace is a linear map $\tr:L(V)\to\mathbb{R}$, so $D\tr(x)=\tr$ for every $x\in L(V)$. That answers your first question.

For the third question, we just use the chain rule. Define $p_n:L(V)\to L(V)$ by $p_n(x)=x^n$. You want \begin{align}
D(\tr\circ p_n)(x)u &= (D\tr(x^n)\circ Dp_n(x))u \\
&= \tr\left(\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} x^kux^{n-k-1}\right) \\
&= \sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\tr\left(x^kux^{n-k-1}\right) \\
&= n\tr(x^{n-1}u).
\end{align}

---

**Lemma** (Power rule). *Let $E$ be a Banach algebra and let $p_n:E \to E$ be the map defined by $p_n(x)=x^n$. Then $$Dp_n(x)u=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} x^kux^{n-k-1}.$$ In particular, if $E$ is commutative then $$Dp_n(x)u=nx^{n-1}u,$$ which is just the plain old power rule.*

*Proof.* We use induction on $n$. The case $n=0$ is clear, so suppose the result holds for $n-1$. Since $p_n(x)=xp_{n-1}(x)$, the product rule shows that \begin{align}
Dp_n(x)u &= up_{n-1}(x)+xDp_{n-1}(x)u \\
&= ux^{n-1}+x\sum_{k=0}^{n-2}x^kux^{n-k-2} \\
&= \sum_{k=0}^{n-1}x^kux^{n-k-1}.
\end{align}

Comment: Thank you for your help :). Maybe a stupid question, but what does the u denote? Is that a unit vector? And why is it needed here?

Comment: @user48288: Well as I said, I only know the "proper" Fréchet derivative notation. I'm guessing that your "differential" is the $u$, so maybe you want to say $$df=n\operatorname{tr}(X^{n-1}\,dX).$$

Comment: O ok, I get it now, thank you :).

Answer (score 3):

I found a really good and well understandable explanation here:

[Matrix Calculus - Notes on the Derivative of a Trace, Johannes Traa](http://cal.cs.illinois.edu/~johannes/research/matrix%20calculus.pdf)

It writes matrix calculations as sums, where you can find the derivative with the known rules for scalars. In the end, you can convert the result back to matrix notation.

Comment: You should add brief explanation about what the link says.

Comment: OK thanks for the hint

Comment: The link to "Matrix Calculus ... " did not work for me; I found it at http://paulklein.ca/newsite/teaching/matrix%20calculus.pdf